# Issue with getting CheckBox value in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a GridView that contains a CheckBox control.  Once the users check the rows that they want, they click a button and I have to update the database for each checked row.

I have the code to iterate trough the gridview rows and look at the checkbox value, but its always false, even if its checked.  I do get a reference to the checkbox in ignore but it is always false.  What am I missing here?

aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Ignore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdNotReceived.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox ignore = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkIgnore");

            if (ignore.Checked)
            {
                // Update Database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdNotReceived" runat="server"
    Width="600px"
    CssClass="mGrid"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"/>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Store" HeaderText="Store" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Dept" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RefNumber" HeaderText="RefNumber" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor" HeaderText="Vendor" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIgnore" runat="server" Checked="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIgnore" runat="server" Checked="false" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

GridView databind method:

```
protected void LoadExceptions()
{
    Database db = new Database();
    SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();

    sql.CommandText = "getSobeysNotReceived";

    this.grdNotReceived.DataSource = db.GetSprocDR(sql);
    this.grdNotReceived.DataBind();

    db.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you change `<ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkIgnore" runat="server" Checked="false" /></ItemTemplate>` to be `true`, do you get that value when checking the state of the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, I get true when making that change.  Why would it not pick up the user entered value, could it have anything to do with using master pages?

Comment: It's really hard to say since I don't know the structure of how you have things setup.  Is the checkbox on your master page or a child page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your databinding function ( `LoadExceptions()` ) is being called somwhere on the page load (like the `Load` event or class constructor) then it's overriding the changes the user has made in the form.

Don't databind if the page is in post back, you can add an `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` before calling `LoadExceptions()` or you can update `LoadExceptions()` to check it:

```
protected void LoadExceptions()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();

        sql.CommandText = "getSobeysNotReceived";

        this.grdNotReceived.DataSource = db.GetSprocDR(sql);
        this.grdNotReceived.DataBind();

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I knew I was missing something obvious, its not the first time I've had a similar issue, I just couldn't see the forest for the trees.